# How to sum some values and group them in mysql

Tags: mysql, sum

I have `Table A` like this:

[image: table_A]

I want to get a result query like this:

[image: Result_sum]

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Help to display the screenshots, and added a relevant tag to the post.

Answer (score 0):

I think your total result may be 45.Result 75 is where come from?I don't know exactly.If you want to 45,you can use the following query

```
    select case When a.Item IS NULL THEN 'total' Else  a.Item  END AS Item,sum(a.value) as value from
     (select Item,sum(value) as value from test1 as t1 where t1.Item='A' or t1.Item='B'   group by  t1.Item )
    as a group by a.Item WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: Sorry, i missed some info. The empty item on the resut query is the sum of "empty"+C. A and B remain sumed each one.